# Activity buttons unavailable in Cases, but available in other objects

Tags: lightning, page-layout, activities, global-actions

I'm having a hard time dealing with activity buttons (new task, record a call, new event, send email) in the Case Lightning page, although they do appear in other objects (pages in Spanish).

*Activities section in the Account detail page*

[image: This is the account activities section]

*Activities section in the Case detail page*

[image: This is the case activities section]

I've tried:

- Editing the Case page layout (it has all the buttons in the lightning actions)
- Reviewing the global actions (I even added an action)
- Checked profiles

...and nothing seems to work. I don't know what else to do!!

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Best

Bernardo

Answer (score 0):

For those who didn't know, Cases behave differently from other objects.

The Lightning component that includes the "New task, New event..." is CHATTER FEED.

So I solved it, adding the Chatter Feed component into the Case Lightning page.

Sorry for any inconveniences, and hope anyone else having this problem gets this as the proper answer.

Best